# excluir coluna de select *

Tags: php, sql

Tenho uma api que retorna os dados do usuario em json, porem queria retornar todos os dados, exceto a senha, teria alguma forma sem ser fazer select em todos os campos exceto a senha?  estou fazendo assim atualmente:

```
    if ($autenticado) {
    $resultado = $sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_alunos WHERE email = :EMAIL LIMIT 1",array(
        ":EMAIL"=>$usermail[0]
    ));
    $response = json_encode($resultado);
}else{
    return $response->withStatus(401);
}
```

Comment: Não, ou manda todos ou especifica cada um.

Comment: Pode nos informar qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados? _Oracle Database, mariaDB, PostgreSQL_ etc.

Comment: to usando mysql

Answer (score 1):

Se você não quer que somente uma coluna apareça você tem que fazer o select com o nome de todas as outras menos da coluna que você não quer, não tem como fazer um "select *" menos uma coluna especifica mas sim adicionando somente as colunas que você quer.